# SQL 2012 Schema/Data Compare In VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, compare, schema

I've been searching everywhere to find out if there is a current way to do a schema and data compare for SQL 2012 database using the existing Schema/Data compares currently included in VS 2010 Ultimate.

The best I have been able to come up with is a silly add-on tool (SSDT Power Tools) that is not nearly on the same level of usability for schema compares and does not do data compares.

Unfortunately we went ahead and setup a new server with SQL 2012 and were prepared to migrate our current production to it when I learned all the good tool we used to use would not work and that there is no backwards compatibility for compares from 2012 to any previous database version with the SSDT.

I'm looking for any help resolving my issue as my alternative is to have to throw away the 2012 server and deploy everything to a 2008 R2 as our work requires us to constantly be able to do data compares.

Comment: If this is a serious need, why not buy an established tool that does this better than Microsoft could (even if it satisfied all of your requirements)? e.g. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/ other tools here http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: Aaron - To answer your question it perhaps may stem from many not having the need for the red-gate tools because what comes out of the box in Ultimate is sufficient.  Companies who have spent the cost of Premier/Ultimate do not want to pay the cost for Red-Gate when they never have had to up until now.

Comment: I'll also add that SSDT cannot compare with the standard db project for VS. This means that if you install it, not only you'll have to convert the projects, but also everyone using the code will have to install SSDT. Same observation for VS2012. Also, apparently, there will be updates to VS2012 in order to include schema and data compare in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

A couple points of clarification.  As mentioned for schema / data compares, best is to use a commercial tool, such as Red-Gate's SQL-Compare.  For completeness though, I'll add a couple of other points:

1. SSDT does do schema compares across versions and editions of SQL Server.  At this time it does not do data compares.  For more about SSDT, check out my [blog posts](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/?s=ssdt) on that topic.
2. You may be able to mitigate the version problem by setting the database compatibility level to something less that SQL Server 2012 as shown in the picture below from SSMS.

[image: Database Compatibility Setting for SQL Server 2012 in SSMS]

Comment: Just an FYI. I am having the same problem, and the answer for #2 didn't work for me. My environment is ... Source = SQL2008R2.SQL2008(100) and Target = SQL2012.SQL2008(100). Same error.

Comment: For the record, this option doesn't work in any way. Microsoft's been very clear about this, it doesn't work. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/355d535f-4a09-4a02-84fb-679b053eb829/vs2010-data-compare-sql-2012

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Master Data](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/530c546a-fdd3-4589-b2b2-e3c4aab13fba) `visual studio addin` to compare `sql server databases` .. It's `lightweight(1mb)` and also includes some advance feature over `SSDT` ..